# Trying to prove various things about (in)equalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-verification, peano-axioms, natural-numbers

After defining things like natural numbers and addition, I'd like to prove some things about the operator $\leq$ and ask if they are correct.

**Definition 1**: Let $a$ and $b$ be natural numbers. We say that $a \geq b$ (or $b \leq a$) iff we have $a = b + m$ for some natural number $m$.

**Definition 2**: We say natural number $a$ is *positive* iff $a \neq 0$.

1. **Order is reflexive**: $a \geq a$. **Proof**: $a = a + m$ reduces to $0 = m$ by cancellation law, so this relationship holds for $m=0$.
2. **Order is transitive**: If $a \geq b$ and $b \geq c$, then $a \geq c$. **Proof**: Let $j,k$ be natural numbers. Then we can write $a = b + j$ and $b = c + k$. This also means $a = c + k + j$. Let $m = k + j$, a natural number. Then we can write $a = c + m$, and therefore $a \geq c$.
3. **Order is anti-symmetric**: If $a \geq b$ and $b \geq a$ then $a=b$. **Proof**: Let $j,k$ be natural numbers. Then by definition we can write $a = b + j$ and $b = a + k$. By substitution, $a = a + k + j$. By cancellation law, $0 = k + j$. By the two subclaims 3.a. and 3.b. we have $k=j=0$. So $a = b + 0$ and $b = a + 0$, which in both cases simplify to $a = b$.

   3.a. **Subclaim**: If $a$ is positive natural number, then $a+b$ is a positive natural number for natural number $b$. **Proof**: We use induction. If $b=0$, then $a+0 = a$ which is a positive natural number. For the inductive step, suppose $a+b$ is a positive natural number. Then we must show $a+S(b)$ is a positive natural number. $a+S(b) = S(a+b)$ by the definition of addition, which cannot be $0$ by Peano's third axiom.

   3.b. **Subclaim** If $0 = a+b$ for natural numbers $a,b$, then $a=0$ and $b=0$. **Proof**: Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$. If $a \neq 0$, then $a$ is positive. But if $a$ is positive, $a+b$ is positive, and cannot be $0$ by subclaim 3.a. Likewise, if $b \neq 0$, $b + a$ is positive, and cannot be $0$ either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, I think a little cleaner is to go the other way around:  we know that $a=a+0$, and therefore $a=a+m$ for some $m$, and therefore $a \le a$.

It's a little cleaner, for if you start with $a=a+m$, and then say "by cancellation law this reduces to $m=0$", you seem to be merely saying that $a=a+m$ implies that $m=0$, but you need to show just the other way around: that $m=0$ implies $a=a+m$, and hence that there is some $m$ such that $a=a_m$

Also: going this way, you don;t need to refer to any kind of cancellation law which, if you start out with basic axioms, is a good bit more complicated than proving any of these!

Comment: I used subclaim 3a to prove subclaim 3b (I didn't know where else to put these two claims for the time being)

Comment: @user525966 Oh, right! I didn't see that, my fault! I do believe that you can (need to?!) do 1 a little more cleanly